# How to record my microphone on Windows 7?

Tags: recording, microphone

I want to make a podcast kind of thing and record what I am saying on the microphone and then export it as an MP3. What is a good simple program to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) for this. It's a totally free audio recorder and editor. You can export into any format, but don't forget to fetch the "[mp3 export plugin](http://lame.buanzo.com.ar/)".

Answer (score 0):

Windows has already integrate a sound recorder on its own. But if you want more feature then a 3rd party recorder is recommended